# galaxy s3 - clicking/crackling sound when button is pressed on headset

Tags: audio, headphones

I listen to music on my international galaxy s3 with the included headset quite a bit.

I don't know if this is a feature or bug but whenever I press a button on the headset's controls (volume, skip track, etc), there is a crackling/clicking sound for each press.  It happens when there is no music playing as well. I know it is not the headset but the phone itself.

Is there a fix for this? What is causing this?